# Проверить наличие элемента в блоке с помощью JS

Tags: javascript

Есть блок с возможными 3 баннерами (элементами с разными классами). Нужно сделать так чтоб когда в нем присутствует баннер_3, первые 2 не отображались, и если присутствует только 1 и 2, то чтоб баннер_1 не отображался. Можно с добавлением класса либо просто стиля "display: none"

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="banner1">Баннер_1</div>
    <div class="banner2">Баннер_2</div>
    <div class="banner3">Баннер_3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос Ваши попытки решить эту интересную задачу.

Comment: Свою попытку я уже добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.block>div[class^='banner']:not(:last-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="banner1">Баннер_1</div>
  <div class="banner2">Баннер_2</div>
  <div class="banner3">Баннер_3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block>.banner3~.banner2,
.block>.banner3~.banner1,
.block>.banner2~.banner1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="banner3">Баннер_3</div>
  <div class="banner2">Баннер_2</div>
  <div class="banner1">Баннер_1</div>
</div>
```